# Can we please grow up here?

Tags: discussion

Seems that everytime I disagree with someone, a serial downvoting binge is launched. I thought this was a forum for "professionals". I guess I was wrong:

-2  47 mins ago     downvote    Addressing burnout when applying for a new job

-2  47 mins ago     downvote    Convincing my manager to let me work from home

-2  48 mins ago     downvote    My boss gave me everyone's pay by mistake and mine is lower, how can I increase it?

-2  48 mins ago     downvote    How do I ask for a higher compensation when the work I'm doing is meant for higher ranks?

-2  57 mins ago     downvote    Should I hand in my resignation at the end of the month or when I decide to leave?

-2  58 mins ago     downvote    Implications of refusing a 'software engineer' role working for people who were forced to hire me?

-2  1 hour ago  downvote    How can I ensure future coworkers do not see my break schedule as laziness?

-2  1 hour ago  downvote    How to deal with unskilled co-workers?

-2  1 hour ago  downvote    Professionalism and Rejecting Job Offers

-2  1 hour ago  downvote    What to do after being passed over for a promotion

-2  1 hour ago  downvote    How/where can I get external feedback for improving programming style and general work habits?

-2  1 hour ago  downvote    Can a “not-so-good” project on a resume hurt my chances?

-4  26 mins ago     2 events     How should students applying for internships/co-ops mention classes they have taken and the things they 
accomplished in class?

Comment: Its understandable to be annoyed, however most downvoting-sprees are the result of one individual, and  not the community as a whole. As phrased, your post reads as a rant aimed at the community as a whole, and will likely get downvoted and/or closed.

Comment: @Rachel  - since the downvoter(s)? choose to _disappear within the crowd_  and are permitted to do so, IMO **we** is appropriate. It doesn't necessarily mean everyone in the community, but members who have chosen to hide themselves within the community and cannot be identified otherwise.

Answer (score 10):

If this is from serial downvoting, I wouldn't worry too much about it because it should be reversed within 24 hours.

Here is the [official explanation of the serial voting reversal functionality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/265769).